# Facebook audience network android studio --> ads:AdQuality:unspecified

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-audience-network

Getting below error for facebook-audience-network

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>    Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find ads:AdQuality:unspecified.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/ads/AdQuality/unspecified/AdQuality-unspecified.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/ads/AdQuality/unspecified/AdQuality-unspecified.jar
>            file:/Users/jaydonga/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/ads/AdQuality/unspecified/AdQuality-unspecified.pom
>            file:/Users/jaydonga/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/ads/AdQuality/unspecified/AdQuality-unspecified.jar
>            file:/Users/jaydonga/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/ads/AdQuality/unspecified/AdQuality-unspecified.pom
>            file:/Users/jaydonga/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/ads/AdQuality/unspecified/AdQuality-unspecified.jar
>        Required by:
>            Ganesha:app:unspecified > com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.12.0

Comment: Please check the below link. It has solved the issue for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365490/android-studio-issue-could-not-find-adsadqualityunspecified